# How to merge cells in a HTML table, and "desmerge" it after?

Tags: html, html-table

I've just figured out the *colspan* attribute.
And I could make this:

```
┌-----------------------------------------------┐
|       |          |                     |      |
|-------+----------+----------+----------+------|
|       |          |          |          |      |     
|-------+----------+---------------------+------|
|       |          |          |          |      |
|-------+----------+---------------------+------|
|       |          |          |          |      |
└-----------------------------------------------┘
```

But what I really want to do it's some like this:

```
┌-----------------------------------------------┐
|       |          |                     |      |
|-------+----------+----------+----------+------|
|       |          |          |          |      |     
|-------+----------+---------------------+------|
|       |          |          |          |      |
|-------+----------+----------+----------+------|
|                  |                     |      |
└-----------------------------------------------┘
```

Comment: You can use colspan on each individual `td`.

Comment: Actually, I know this, but I didn't tried it correctly. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EssTg/)**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/FksE4/1/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1</td>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, of course. Now I am blaming myself to not have tried enough to such a silly thing. I have just used colspan incorrectly on the last row. Thank you very much. And some extra thanks for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

`colspan` will work in any `td` or `th` cell, you just have to count them out correctly, e.g.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This would give you the table you described.